# Issue in Linking a C Library compiled with CMake in Android.

Tags: android, c, linux, android-ndk, cmake

I am building a daemon on Android Platform. For which I have cross compiled the existing code, which is present in Linux to Android. Please consider my below 2 cases -

1. I cross compile the code using Cmake with Android NDK-15 and push manually to the board on which Android Code is available. The path in which we push is /system/lib. Then if I try to execute my daemon (which is also pushed manually to /system/bin ) everything works fine.

But,

2 The cross compiled library have been pushed into the AOSP code by writing an Android.mk file written in vendor specific folder. I have used BUILD_PREBUILTS method and was successfully able to push the libraries to /system/lib. Now, when I try to execute my application (Compiled with CMake ) I get a linker error.

Below is the error which I get ( Reference Example ) -

1. Below is the folder structure -

Total Number of folders - 3

```
  a. abc folder which produces output libabc.so and links to libdef.so and 
     libghi.so 

  b. def folder which produces output libdef.so 

  c. ghi folder which produces output libghi.so
```

2. When I push all the 3 libraries (libabc.so, libdef.so, libghi.so ) directly in /system/lib and my executable (drive_test) which links all the 3 libraries, I have no issue. But, when I push it along with AOSP build I get the following error on execution of the executable (drive_test) -

   a. Unable to link ../abc/def.so file.

I am unable to debug how to solve this linker issue. I am not getting whether it is because of CMake (or) any other issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to make a system daemon (something that goes in /system/bin), don't use the NDK. Just use the AOSP build system.

In mydaemon/Android.bp (make sure to add this path to the root Android.bp file):

```
cc_library {
    name: "libmylib",
    srcs: ["mylib.cpp"],
}

cc_binary {
    name: "mydaemon",
    srcs: ["mydaemon.cpp"],
    shared_libs: ["libmylib"],
}
```

The build system will deal with getting libraries and binaries into the right place for you.